# IE not correctly applying css/scripts on HTML pages (works on .php)

Tags: php, html, css, internet-explorer

I have an issue with IE not properly loading scripts/stylesheets correctly on plain HTML pages, while loading them perfectly fine on .php pages.

Homepage which is php, correctly loads the popup and it is styled:
[link removed]

Example product page, does not load the popup correctly
[link removed]

This php/html difference works perfectly fine on the other browsers, but it is just IE that it does not work well with. Any assistance would be great

I've tested this on IE 9 and below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its because you have a comment *before* your doctype .. which is causing IE to display in quirks mode (equivalent to an old version of IE). Nothing should precede this, not even white space.

`<!-- categories3_eof //--><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">`

Include the comment *after* the doctype and IE will treat your DTD appropriately ..

`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><!-- categories3_eof //-->`